# Save file to local disk from stream of google docs api file from javascript

Tags: javascript

We get string in responseText when request is given to get a file from Google Docs Api in JavaScript.

So now we are taking that string to code behind and trying to save, but after save we are getting file corrupted error.

Below is the JavaScript function where I get the file data in string in xhr.responseText:

```
   var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;//get the access token
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('GET', file.attributes.path, false);//Pass filename to from Google docs
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
                xhr.onload = function () {                
              managerDialog.uploadFile(xhr.responseText, file.text);//We get string as response in responseText
               };
```

In Code behind code I have passed xhr.responseText to fileContent:

```
  var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileContent);//Converting string to  UTF8 byte
  MemoryStream st2 = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);//Creating Memory Stream. 
 FileStream file = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
      byte[] bytes1 = new byte[st2.Length];
      st2.Read(bytes1, 0, (int)st2.Length);//Reading Stream.
      file.Write(bytes1, 0, bytes1.Length);
      file.Close();//close the file.
      st2.Close();//close the stream.
```

Then I have saved in file. After saving when I tried to open it is saying file is corrupted.

Could any one Please Help me.

It ate 3 days in finding solution, but not yet got the solution.

Comment: it's possible via flash